# Why does this leave me with 2 identical DF?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF as such. I want to merge the columns:

```
DF=
ID    token
0     here
1     I
2     am

DF2 = DF
DF2["token"] = DF["token"] + "-" + DF["ID"].str.split(' ').str[-1]


DF2=
ID    token
0     here-0
1     I-1
2     am-2
```

However when I look at both DF, they look the same:

```
DF.to_csv("DF.csv")
DF2.to_csv("DF2.csv")

DF=
ID    token
0     here-0
1     I-1
2     am-2

DF2=
ID    token
0     here-0
1     I-1
2     am-2
```

Why is that? Shouldn't only DF2 have the new format??!

Comment: make a copy DF2=DF.copy()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned `DF2 = DF` which just points the name `DF2` at the same object as the name `DF`.  That means that what ever you do to change that object is reflected when you access that object by either name.

Instead use

```
DF2 = DF.copy()
```

This will create a new object that is a copy of the object that `DF` points to and will be independent.